# Harish-Chandra's submersive principle on closed subsets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions, p-adic-analysis

Harish-Chandra's submersion principle says the following. Let $X,Y$ be two manifolds of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively. Let $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective smooth map which is submersive everywhere. Let $\omega_X,\omega_Y$ be two differential forms on $X$ and $Y$ respectively of degree $m$ and $n$. Then for every $\alpha\in C_c^\infty(X)$, there exists a unique function $F_\alpha\in C_c^\infty(Y)$ such that 
$$\int_X \alpha(x) \phi(\pi(x))d\omega_X =\int_Y F_\alpha(y)\phi(y)d\omega_Y$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(Y)$.

[Reference: Harish-Chandra, $\textit{Invariant distributions on Lie Algebras}$, American Journal of Math, $\textbf{86}$(1964),271-309,

The p-adic version can be found in

Harish-Chandra, Notes by G.van Dijk, $\textit{Harmonic Analysis on reductive p-adic groups}$, Lecture Notes in Math, $\textbf{162}$, p.48-49.]

Since the defining property of $F_\alpha$ is given by an integral, it seems very hard to detect values of $F_\alpha$ on closed subsets of $Y$. For example, we consider the following situation. Suppose that $X=X_1\times X_2$, and we identify $X_1$ with $X_1\times 0$, where $0\in X_2$ is a fixed point. Let $\pi, Y$ be as in the first paragraph. If we know 
$$\int_{X_1}\alpha(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))d\omega_{X_1}=0$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\pi(X_1))$, can we conclude that the restriction of $F_\alpha$ to the closed set $\pi(X_1)$ is zero?

If the above is wrong, let us consider a weaker form of the above problem. Given $\beta\in C_c^\infty(X_1)$, if 
$$\int_{X_1}\beta(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))dx_1=0,$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\pi(X_1))$, could we find a function $\alpha\in C_c^\infty(X)$ such that $\alpha|_{X_1}=\beta$ and $F_\alpha|_{\pi(X_1)}=0$?

A slightly different way to formulate this question is as follows. Denote $Y_1=\pi(X_1)$. Thus $\pi|_{X_1}:X_1\rightarrow Y_1$ is also submersive (is this true?). Thus Harish-Chandra's submersion principle gives a map $\beta\mapsto F_\beta$ from $C_c^\infty(X_1)$ to $C_c^\infty(Y_1)$ which satisfies 
$$\int_{X_1}\beta(x_1)\phi(\pi(x_1))d\omega_{X_1}=\int_{Y_1}F_\beta(y)\phi(y)d\omega_{Y_1}$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(Y_1)$. Is there any chance to make the following diagram commutative(at least in the p-adic case)?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C_c^\infty(X) @>{HC}>> C_c^\infty(Y)\\
    @V res V V @VV res V\\
    C_c^\infty(X_1) @>>HC> C_c^\infty(Y_1)
\end{CD}
where the horizontal arrows are Harish-Chandra decent, and the vertical arrows are restrictions. In the p-adic case, the restrictions are surjective.

Comment: +1 for subversive mappings.

Comment: Can't you get the value of $F_\alpha(y_0)$ as $\lim \int F_\alpha(y)\varphi_n(y)d\omega_Y(y)$ where $\varphi_n$ is a sequence of test functions whith intergal $1$ whose supports shrink to $\lbrace y_0\rbrace$?

Comment: I don't understand the example. What are $Y$ and $\pi$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks for your comment. The notation $Y$ and $\pi$ are explained in the first paragraph. That's a natural idea to use $\varphi_n$. But I cannot figure out the details.

Comment: In the first paragraph you give the general setting. But after *For example, we consider the following situation...* you don't say what $Y$ and $\pi$ should be for this particular $X$.

Comment: No further requirements for Y and pi.